# Laravel Swift add UUID

Tags: swift, laravel

I'm sending mass messages with custom messages per subscriber, when I get the bounce-back I use my own cocktail to read the STMP emails.
What I haven't figure it out is how to add a unique ID for each email that is sent out, so in my bounce-back I can read the email's code and look for that particular ID, currently when I read the bounce I look for the recipient email compare to what I have based on creation date plus the email...
Is not efficient and 20 emails out of 1K or so gets lost cuz I can't find in bounce the headers due to some servers custom messages although it does return headers but I have nothing to compared with... 
So is there a way to add this UUID in Swift services?
 I have seen that Swift is adding its own UUID but I haven't been able to retrieve it, when the message is sent I want that UUID so that I can save it and then latter I can read it from the bounces... 
So, if I can't retrieve it, can I add my own?
I wanna have a relation email and UUID that was use when that message was sent.

```
 $message_out = (new \Swift_Message($out->subject))
             ->setFrom($out->from_email, $out->from_name)
             ->setTo($out->email)
             ->setBody($content, 'text/html')
             ->setReplyTo('noreply@foo.com', 'No reply');

 $message_out->send($mensaje_mail, $errors_sent);
```

Is this a header I can add the retrieve it in the bounce-back messages?

Thank you.

Comment: It's a html email ? You can 'hide' the uuid in the body, with a class='hidden' ? And parse your return email ?

Comment: @SamuelAialaFerreira, yes it is an HTML the thing is that the bounce-back email not always return the original body or as an attachment, is just a bounce-back message letting me know if there was an error at delivery such as inbox full, email doesn't exist or wrong host name... things like that.